# Downloading video files of specific size

Tags: python, python-requests

To do:

- Download a video from url. The downloading should stop once a specific file size has been reached.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
import requests

with open(local_file_name, 'w') as f:
    r = requests.get(url,stream=True)
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=5000000):  
        if chunk: 
            f.write(chunk)
            break
```

I used 'break' after writing that chunk of specific size to the file.
Though the file is being created and the size of it is 5 MB, I am not able to view the file as it throwing error while opening.

Comment: try chunk_size=1024

Comment: Doesn't it make sense? You save an incomplete file, but you still think it can be opened normally?

Comment: You want to download a streaming video for example and want to be able to see up to a point?

Comment: @sraw I will try adding f.close before break.

Comment: To be fair, there is no requirement in the "todo" that the file is playable - maybe you're done?

Comment: @Eypros yeah that example is relatable

Comment: @PeterGibson I would like to find a better solution for the problem.

Comment: Try opening the file in `'wb'` mode (write binary)

Comment: @PeterGibson 'wb' did not work.

Comment: Can you post the URL you're testing with so others can try it?